# How do I get users to enter their username after logging in?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I want users to enter a username before they get to the dashboard view (if it's the first time they ever logged in) and that "Enter a unique username" will only appear once after their first login and never appear again. I'm not sure do I involve the HomeController and dashboard view(timeline) or not and whether I should just do an @if and @else statement to distinguish between username = null or not.

Home Controller:

```
use Auth;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return view('dashboard.index');
    }

    return view('home');
}

}
```

This is my User.php:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
protected $table = 'users';

protected $fillable = [
    'username',
    'first_name',
    'last_name',        
    'email', 
    'password',
    'location',
    'gender',
    'date_of_birth',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 
    'remember_token',
];

public function getName()
{
    if ($this->first_name && $this->last_name) {
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";

    }

    if ($this->first_name) {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

    return null;

}

    public function getUsername()
{
    if ($this->first_name && $this->last_name) {
    return "{$this->first_name}.{$this->last_name}";

    }

    if ($this->first_name) {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

    return null;

}

public function getNameOrUsername()
{
    return $this->getName() ?: $this->username;
}

public function getUsernameOrName()
{
    return $this->getUsername() ?: $this->username;
}

public function getFirstNameOrUsername()
{
    return $this->first_name ?: $this->username;
}
}
```

getusername.blade.php:

```
<div style="min-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; top: 75px;">
<div class="row" style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; border: 2px solid #000; padding: 40px;">
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="width: 600px; color: #999; padding: 44.5px 0;">
    <h3 style="color: #000; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;">Enter a username</h3>
        <form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('dashboard.getusername') }}">
        <div>
            <div>Your public username is the same as your Profile address:

                <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <div>mostwanted.com/<span id="display_name">
                    <script>
                    $('#username').keyup(function () {
                    $('#display_name').text($(this).val());
                    });
                    </script>
                    </span></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="username" class="control-label">Choose a username</label>
                    <input style="width: 456px;" placeholder="e.g.&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->getUsernameOrName() }}" type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" value="">
                        @if ($errors->has('username'))
                            <span class="help-block" style="font-size: 12px; margin-bottom: 0;">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</span>
                        @endif
                </div>
                <div>Note:&nbsp;Your username cannot be changed and should include your authentic name&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                <button style="float: right;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save username</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">                
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

UsernameController:

```
use Auth;
use DB;
use MostWanted\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class UsernameController extends Controller
{
public function getUsername()
{
    return view('dashboard.getusername');
}

public function postUsername(Request $request)
{

    $username = Auth::user()->username;

    if (!$username) {
        return view('dashboard.getusername');
    }

    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|unique:users|regex:/^[A-Za-z0-   9.]+$/|max:50',
        ]);

    User::create([
        'username' => $request->input('username'),
        ]);     

    return view('dashboard.index');

}
}
```

The last time I did it was `@if (Auth::user()->username===null)` it only goes to the form for entering a username even if I've entered a username already (redirect to the username form only).

P.S I have no idea why the `<script>` doesn't work. I want the `<span>` to display whatever is being entered in the `<input>`

EDIT*:

routes.php:

```
/** 
*Home + Entering Username
*/
Route::get('/', [
'uses' => '\MostWanted\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index',
'as' => 'home',
]);

Route::get('/', ['middleware' => 'nousername', function () {

[
'uses' => '\MostWanted\Http\Controllers\UsernameController@getUsername',
'as' => 'dashboard.getusername',
];

[
'uses' => '\MostWanted\Http\Controllers\UsernameController@postUsername',
];

}]);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

/**
*Authenication
*/

#Sign up
Route::get('/signup', [
'uses' => '\MostWanted\Http\Controllers\AuthController@getSignup',
'as' => 'auth.signup',
'middleware' => ['guest'],
]);

Route::post('/signup', [
'uses' => '\MostWanted\Http\Controllers\AuthController@postSignup',
'middleware' => ['guest'],
]);

#Log in
Route::get('/login', [
'uses' => '\MostWanted\Http\Controllers\AuthController@getSignin',
'as' => 'auth.signin',
'middleware' => ['guest'],
]);

Route::post('/login', [
'uses' => '\MostWanted\Http\Controllers\AuthController@postSignin',
'middleware' => ['guest'],
]);

#Log out
Route::get('/logout', [
'uses' => '\MostWanted\Http\Controllers\AuthController@getSignOut',
'as' => 'auth.signout',
]);

/**
*Search
*/

Route::get('/search', [
'uses' => '\MostWanted\Http\Controllers\SearchController@getResults',
'as' => 'search.results',
]);

/**
*User profile
*/

Route::get('/user/{username}', [
'uses' => '\MostWanted\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getProfile',
'as' => 'profile.index',
]);

});
```

NoUsernameMiddleware:

```
namespace MostWanted\Http\Middleware;

use Auth;
use Closure;

class NoUsernameMiddleware
{
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
if(!Auth::user()->username) {
    return redirect("/choose_username");
}
    return $next($request);
}
}
```

Comment: What is outputted if you put `var_dump(Auth::user()->username);` in place of the if statement where you tested if it was null? Also, though it wouldn't make a difference here, you can use the `is_null($var)` function for checking null variables.

Comment: @Hiphop03199 The `@if` statement was in a blade template. I am trying to set up a new controller and new blade template. The method above was before, when I tried to fit everything into the HomeController. 

I will edit the above methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should use is_null function to test your username
2. Can you give us the controller's method associated to route('dashboard.getusername') ? Maybe the form works but the username is not saved in database

Comment: It's the UsernameController. I also opened MySQL Workbench and looked into the username, the username(s) exists.

Comment: Did you try to put the if in your controller ? like : `if (is_null(Auth()::user->username)) { return view('dashboard.getusername'); } else { return view('dashboard.index'); }`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to handle this case with a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware).

To create one, open the shell in the root of your project and type:

```
php artisan make:middleware NoUsernameMiddleware
```

A file called `NoUsernameMiddleware.php` will be created in `app/Http/Middleware/`; open it and add these lines in the handle function.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!Auth::user()->username){
        return redirect("/path/to/username/input")
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Register it in `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...,
    ...,
    'nousername' => \App\Http\Middleware\AgeMiddleware::class,
];
```

Apply the middleware to the dashboard route:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', ['middleware' => 'nousername', function () {
    //
}]);
```

Then you can create the Controller and the view to handle the form where all of users without an username will be redirected to.

Comment: I followed your instructions and I feel like I'm getting there. But when it redirects me to the username form, `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161` pops up. Are there some settings in Laravel 5.2 that is preventing what I'm trying to do? I cleared my database and migrated a new table where username isn't nullable anymore, so my username doesn't exist.

Comment: You did something wrong in the routes or in the url to go

Comment: My apologies, I'm very very inexperienced. I have added my routes.php in the question.

Comment: Where is the route to /choose_username ?

Comment: In the middleware. `mostwanted.dev:8000` will lead to the home page if user isn't logged in and will lead to the dashboard if the user is logged in.

Comment: I created the route `/choose_username` (I put the route outside the middleware as well.) But then it renders my `('home')` route undefined. I want the timeline and not logged in home page route to be `('/')`

Also, when I log out I get `ErrorException in NoUsernameMiddleware.php line 11:
Trying to get property of non-object` 

Line 11: `if(!Auth::user()->username)`

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object means that the user is not logged in